# NSMutableArray not saved NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a NSMutableArray with NSUSerDefault and then open the array.
Here some code:

```
-(IBAction)btnSave{    
Class *aClass = [[Class alloc]init];    
aClass.idClass=@"aaaxxx";    
aClass.nameClass=@"hello";
[myArray addObject:aClass];
NSUserDefaults *arrayDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[arrayDefault setObject:myArray forKey:@"savedArray"];
[arrayDefault synchronize]; 
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *savedArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
    if(savedArray!=NULL){
        myArray=savedArray;
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

when I compile and when I push the button, this is what I read on log output:

```
[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<Class: 0x8452b40>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values
```

and obviously when I reopen the view the array is not loaded. 
any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` allows only Premitive DataTypes to be store in it. if you want to store your custom class Object then use following code, for more Detail refer this [IOS Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html)

```
//create an array with your custom class objects

Class *aClass = [[Class alloc]init];
aClass.idClass=@"aaaxxx";
aClass.nameClass=@"hello";

[myArray addObject:aClass];

//convert your array to `NSData` object using `NSKeyedArchiver`    
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];

//store it to `NSUserDefaults`
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"myArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//convert your stored Object back to `NSData` using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`    
NSData *storedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
NSArray *storedArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData]];

NSLog(@"%@",storedArr[0]);
```

Comment: It works!!! I only changed one thing: on "viewDidLoad" i've put :

if(storedData!=NULL){
    myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData]];
    }

Comment: yes that checks whether an Array is already stored in UserDefaults or not. good work.

Comment: ok it's working... but no so good. the issue is when I want to add a new object to the loaded array. When I create the new object and i add it to the array with [myArray addObject:newObj] then i need to reload the TableView and when I arrive to the part of "cellForRowAtIndexPath" : 

 if (cell == nil) {
  
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:sLoadNibNamed owner:self options:NULL];
  cell = [self typeNibLoadCell:aEquipaggio.idMembro];
 }

the app goes in exception: [UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView idMembro]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: it may not be updated in your NSUserDefaults, if you forget to synchronize and reload your NSArray then it would happen. and code i have posted is for reference, you have to make changes according to your app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement NSCoding protocol in your model object `Class`. It is needed to serialize and deserialize non standard data to `NSUserDefaults`.

Now you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert the object to data and store in userDefaults. Use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to convert the data back to the object from defaults.

```
//h file
@interface Class : NSObject<NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *idClass;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nameClass;


//m File

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{

    [aCoder encodeObject:self.idClass forKey:@"IDClass"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.nameClass forKey:@"NameClass"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.idClass = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"IDClass"];
        self.nameClass = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"NameClass"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

After implementing the NSCoding you can archive them to store as data in userDefaults

```
//Saving array
Class *aClass = [[Class alloc]init];    
aClass.idClass=@"aaaxxx";    
aClass.nameClass=@"hello";

[myArray addObject:aClass];

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"savedArray"];
[defaults synchronize]; 

//Retrieving 

NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you implement NSCoding in you object class. The in order to save/load the NSMutableArray of those objects you can do:

```
- (void) loadArray {
    //Loading the NSMutableArray
    NSData *arrayData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ArrayKey"];
    myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver arrayData];
}

-(void) saveArray {
    //Saving the NSMutableArray
    NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayData forKey:@"ArrayKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

For more info I suggest looking at a longer tutorial. For example Ray Wenderlich's [How to Save your App Data with NSCoding And NSFileManager](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) is a good one.