# Error when trying to store array of nsdictionaries in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

Basically I have an array of NSdictionaries that I want to store in NSUserDefaults. 
pageDict is a local NSDictionary
LyteData is a Singleton class used to store stuff
The hierarchy goes from lyteData.textbookDictArray ---> lyteData.pagesDictArray ---> pageDict (NSDictionary)

```
    [pageDict setObject:textbookImage forKey:@"image"];
    [pageDict setObject:textbookName forKey:@"name"];
    [pageDict setObject:page forKey:@"page"];
    [pageDict setObject:nameOfClass forKey:@"class"];

    LyteData *lyteData = [LyteData sharedManager];
    [lyteData.pagesDictArray addObject:pageDict];


    [lyteData.textbookDictArray addObject:lyteData.pagesDictArray];
       NSLog(@"array: %@", lyteData.pagesDictArray);
       NSLog(@"textbook array: %@", lyteData.textbookDictArray);

   //THIS CODE IS FOR SAVING THE ARRAY OF TEXTBOOKS AS USERDEFAULT
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:lyteData.textbookDictArray forKey:@"textbookArray"];
```

I get this error:

```
   Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
        {
        class = hb;
        image = "<UIImage: 0x165c43d0>";
        name = fv;
        page = 25;
    }
) as an NSUserDefaults value for key textbookArray
```

How can I store that array in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` can only store `premitive` objects (eg. NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString etc.) if you want to store custom object in it, you need to use trick. [refer my post here for storing custom class object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519443/nsmutablearray-not-saved-nsuserdefault/16519672#16519672)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to store a `UIImage` to `NSUserDefaults` which is not supported. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620165/iphonehow-can-i-store-uiimage-using-nsuserdefaults) for the solution.

Comment: The more better idea is to store only path in `NSUserDefaults` and store images in to Documents directory of the app.

Comment: I agree with what Akshit says. Storing as an NSData in NSUserDefaults will mean that your image data is always loaded into memory (NSUserDefaults loads the whole plist at once).